# Spring 3.1 Cache Annotation EhCache

Tags: spring, ehcache, spring-annotations

I am using Spring 3.1 Cache using EhCache currently to implement method caching. Consider the code fragment below:

```
@Cacheable("items")
public Item findByPK(int itemID) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE ITEM_ID = ?";
    Item item = getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{itemID}, new ItemRowMapper());
    return item;
}

@Cacheable("items")
public List<Item> findAll() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM ITEM";
    List<Item> items = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql,new ItemRowMapper());
    return items;
}
```

If I call findByPK() it hits the database first, then onwards it hits the cache, so the method caching works. findAll() ditto. However, is there any way to instruct spring to make findByPK() calls recognize the results returned by findAll()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a major hack, but it would give you the functionality you want:

```
@Cacheable("items")
public Item findByPK(int itemID) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE ITEM_ID = ?";
    Item item = getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{itemID}, new ItemRowMapper());
    return item;
}

@Cacheable("items")
public List<Item> findAll() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM ITEM";
    List<Item> items = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql,new ItemRowMapper());
    for (Item item : items){
        removeThenAddToCache(item.getID(), item);
    }
    return items;
}

@CacheEvict(value = "items", key="#itemID")
public void removeThenAddToCache(int itemID, Item item) {
    addToCache(item);
}

@Cacheable(value = "items", key="#itemID")
public Item addToCache(int itemID, Item item) {
    return item;
}
```

Comment: This will only work if you are weaving, not if you are using spring proxies.

Comment: Not working; Not sure what I am using, how do I check? how do I fix?

Comment: if you haven't setup weaving, then you are using the Spring default of proxies.

Comment: You could separate it into another component if you don't want to setup weaving... but that would make it even more of a hack.

Comment: I got another hack working (by repeatedly calling findByPK on findAll), I am good with this...Thanks.

Comment: Your other method may be harder on your database.  I would not recommend that.

Comment: I know, however it is read only data, doing it one time intialization, and it is not too much data either; i know it is not pretty; i guess otherwise i need to couple my code with EhCache api, bypassing the transparency provided by spring, i am tempted to do that....my code does not use hibernate but spring jdbc.i want domain data caching, but spring cache is method caching; hence the need to do work around.